# Reversing sorting order of a stream using Comparator.reversed()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I'm writing a program that reads a string as an input and then outputs 10 most repeated words. Problem is, my order is reversed. I want to output from highest to lowest and it's sorted in opposite order. So I've been looking for a solution and only thing I found is .reversed() method but it says "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". I don't understand this error, cause in the example it was used in a similar situation.

I'm new to streams so I'd like to know a simple way to resolve this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
        words.stream()
                .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""))
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed()) // static method can't be referenced
                .limit(10)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
    }
```

EDIT: I've had keys and values of a map mixed up and edited that. Due to my mistake, Arvind's answer might look a bit different, but it doesn't matter since Map.Entry has both .comparingByKey and .comparingByValue methods.

Comment: In addition to the below answer, you can also use `sorted((Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Long>, Long>comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).reversed())` or better: `sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue()).reversed())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [`Map.Entry.comparingByKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey-java.util.Comparator-)

You can pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()` to `Map.Entry.comparingByKey`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = scanner.nextLine();
         List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
         words.stream()
                 .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""))
                 .map(String::toLowerCase)
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder())) 
                 .limit(10)
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                 .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 5 9 2 7 2 3 9 5 3 1 8 3 6 8 2 3 6 9
4
7
8
6
5
1
9
3
2
```

Comment: It’s worth noting why it works and the question’s code doesn’t. Type inference has limitations when it comes to chained method invocations whereas it works without problems for nested invocations.